# Паттерны объектного программирования.

Tags: ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Здравствуйте.
Какие паттерны объектного программирования по вашему мнению наиболее полезные, эффективные и часто используемые. Ведь паттернов существует много, а таких же полезных, как Singleton или Adapter немного,можно на пальцах пересчитать. Так вот не могли бы вы привести свой небольшой перечень самых полезных паттернов на ваш взгляд? Спасибо.

Comment: по-моему все паттерны одинаково полезны - каждый для своей задачи, вы назвали `Singleton или Adapter` - они, скорее всего, наиболее часто используемы

Comment: Ну в своей практике(web) встречаю много Модель-Вид-Контроллер и, периодически, синглтон.

Comment: Да, я знаю, что паттерны применяются по ситуации. Но хотелось бы знать 5-10 самых часто используемых =)

Comment: [Фасад](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B4_%28%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%29), например. Но с ним аккуратно надо, неграмотно спроектированный имеет свойство превращаться в тыкву. Даже чаще, чем mvc)

Comment: как насчет Strategy? Некоторые паттерны проектирования вложены в сам язык.

Comment: На википедии кстати очень хорошая [статья][1]  
[1]:http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: делайте классы статичными :D как я

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**"Самых полезных"** паттернов нет.

---

Тем не менее, существует набор предопределенных `Design Patterns`, введенных Э.Гаммой и его коллегами, известными как `Gang of Four`.

И есть [**соответствующая книга,**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) которая приводит их подробное описание и возможные сценарии использовании. Обычно `[GoF - Design Patterns]` рекомендуется для прочтения каждому человеку, который склонен называть себя программистом.

---

Хороший пример проекции книги `Design Patterns` на стандартную библиотеку `Java` вы можете найти в ответе на вопрос [**Examples of GoF Design Patterns.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Answer (score 2):

из всех типов я бы в первую очередь выделил паттерны создания и поведенческие + обсервер. лично для меня самыми полезными (зачастую и чаще всего используемыми) являются:

singleton, factory method, lazy initialization, builder
decorator, proxy
observer, template method, state, visitor
dao, mvc